# Get unique visitors by month/year

Tags: sql, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table that track all page views of my app.

```
class Tracking_visits(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users_user.id'), nullable=False)
    ts = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC))
```

This code works fine to get visits grouped by month/year.

```
db.session.query(func.count(Tracking_visits.id), extract('month', Tracking_visits.ts).label('m'), extract('year', Tracking_visits.ts).label('y')).group_by('m', 'y').order_by('m', 'y').all()
```

Now I have another objective. I need to get the total of unique visits. An user can have multiple visits, but in this case, I am interested only **in unique visits by month**. How can I do That?

I read something about `func.distinct()` but I am not sure how to apply it to my query above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the `.query` argument so that `func.count()` operates on `distinct()`, which is taking in `Trackin_visits.user_id` as the argument:

```
db.session.query(func.count(distinct(Tracking_visits.user_id)),
    extract('month', Tracking_visits.ts).label('m'),
    extract('year', Tracking_visits.ts).label('y'))
    .group_by('m', 'y')
    .order_by('m', 'y')
    .all()
```

The documentation for Queries can be found at the following site, and if you scroll down to `Count()` you'll find an example of using distinct this way: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#the-query-object